# Any keyboard shortcut to display Xcode's "Show Find Options"?

Tags: xcode4

Xcode offers several key codes to open the **Find (CMD-F)** or **Find and Replace (CMD-OPT-F)** editor toolbar, but how can I get the **Find Options** to show without having to move my mouse over the magnifying glass and clicking (which takes forever, I misclick, and then have to select the menu item - ugh)?

Answer (score 0):

I have not found a single key to do this, but just discovered that after using 
**CMD-F**
 or 
**CMD-OPT-F**
 that the **Find** search field has focus, and by tapping the 
**down arrow key**
 twice followed by a 
**Return** key, that it opened (do again to close)!

I added a key code sequence to **Butler** so I can use a single key to do this, so use your favorite **Macro** program to do likewise.

EDIT: Just discovered this still works in Xcode 7, you just need to do 2 down-arrows followed by a return.