# Is there a way to set the find options in Xcode9 via keyboard?

Tags: find, keyboard-shortcuts, xcode9

If you want to search for something in Xcode9, <kbd>⌘</kbd><kbd>F</kbd> opens the find bar, <kbd>⇧</kbd><kbd>⌘</kbd><kbd>F</kbd> opens *Find in Project* in the Navigator.
However, I often want to switch between *contains*, *matches* and *regex*, but the dropdowns (see image) to set this are not reachable via keyboard, only mouse.

[image]

For Xcode7, there seemed to be a way (see [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15822453/any-keyboard-shortcut-to-display-xcodes-show-find-options)), but this doesn't work any more.

Does anyone know how to set these options via keyboard in Xcode9?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In macOS *System Preferences -> Keyboard -> Shortcuts*, you have to set **Full Keyboard Access** to **All Controls**.

After that you can <kbd>Tab</kbd> to all the options.

This has worked for *Find in Project* (<kbd>⇧</kbd><kbd>⌘</kbd><kbd>F</kbd>) since Xcode 9.0. For the "normal" find (<kbd>⌘</kbd><kbd>F</kbd>) it was buggy util apple fixed it in [Xcode 9.3](https://developer.apple.com/library/content/releasenotes/DeveloperTools/RN-Xcode/Chapters/Introduction.html).

> Resolved Issues
>
> - The source editor find and replace control now
>     supports Full Keyboard Access. (33666790)